# JOptionPane behaving weird with KeyListener

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am currently working on a Sudoku solver with a GUI. Neither is finished, but the GUI is partly operational.
However I have encountered something weird. The code follows below:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SudokuWindow extends JFrame {
    public SudokuWindow() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->createSudokoWindow());
    }
    
    private void createSudokoWindow() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sudoku!");
        int height = 600;
        int width = 1000;
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        SudokuBoard sB= new SudokuBoard(width/2,width/2,9,9);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Import solvabel setup");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Find solution");
        JTextField t1=new JTextField("0");  
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);
        panel.add(t1);
        mainPanel.add(sB,BorderLayout.WEST);
        mainPanel.add(panel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SudokuWindow();
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SudokuBoard extends JPanel {
      int width, height, rows, cols;
      JFormattedTextField[][] txtM = new JFormattedTextField[9][9];
      
      SudokuBoard(int w, int h, int r, int c) {
            setSize(width = w, height = h);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h));
            for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                    txtM[i][j] = new JFormattedTextField();
                }
            }
            rows = r;
            cols = c;
      }
      
      public void paint(Graphics g) {
            width = getSize().width;
            height = getSize().height;
            
            int rowHt = height / rows;
            int colWt = width / cols;
            JFormattedTextField t;
            
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                    t = txtM[i][j];
                    t.setText("0");
                    t.setSize(rowHt,colWt);
                    t.setMargin(new Insets(0,18,0,0));
                    t.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,26));
                    t.setLocation(i*colWt, j*rowHt);
                    t.addKeyListener(keyListener);
                    if((((j+1) % 9 == 1 || (j+1) % 9 == 2 || (j+1) % 9 == 3) && ((i+1) % 9 == 1 || (i+1) % 9 == 2 || (i+1) % 9 == 3))){
                        t.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
                    } else if(((j+1) % 9 == 7 || (j+1) % 9 == 8 || (j+1) % 9 == 0) && ((i+1) % 9 == 1 || (i+1) % 9 == 2 || (i+1) % 9 == 3)){
                        t.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
                    } else if(((j+1) % 9 == 7 || (j+1) % 9 == 8 || (j+1) % 9 == 0) && ((i+1) % 9 == 7 || (i+1) % 9 == 8 || (i+1) % 9 == 0)){
                        t.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
                    } else if(((j+1) % 9 == 1 || (j+1) % 9 == 2 || (j+1) % 9 == 3) && ((i+1) % 9 == 7 || (i+1) % 9 == 8 || (i+1) % 9 == 0)){
                        t.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
                    } else if(((j+1) % 9 == 4 || (j+1) % 9 == 5 || (j+1) % 9 == 6) && ((i+1) % 9 == 4 || (i+1) % 9 == 5 || (i+1) % 9 == 6)){
                        t.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
                    }
                    add(t);
                }
            }
        }
        
        KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                if(Character.isLetter(e.getKeyChar()) || ((Character) e.getKeyChar()).equals('0')){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input!");
                }
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
        };
}
```

The code works as intended so far except for one thing. When the KeyListener finds a Letter or a 0, the JOptionPane pops up three times. This is kind of annoying, and I don't understand why it does that.

Also I am trying to reach the JFormattedTextFields so I can reset them after a Invalid input but can't reach them through the KeyListener. Is there some nice way to do this?

If anyone could help me figure this out I would greatly appreciate it!

Thank you!

Comment: **Don't override paint().**. Painting methods are for custom painting only. You are NOT doing custom painting. This can cause multiple components to be created and added to the panel every time Swing decides the components needs to be repainted. Your components should be created and added to the panel in the constructor of your class and a `GridLayout` should be used to position the components in a grid

Comment: There is no need for a KeyListener. You can configure the `JFormattedTextField` to use a `MaskFormatter` to only accept numeric digits and you can then use the `setValidCharacters(...)` method to limit the digits from 1-0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**
Your problem is that you are adding another `KeyListener` to each `JFormattedTextField` every time method `paint` is called and each listener is executed. So if...

> the JOptionPane pops up three times

then it means that method `paint` was called three times which caused three listeners to be added to each `JFormattedTextField`.

---

Other general notes regarding your code:

Class `SudokuWindow`:

1. *Swing* application classes, such as your `SudokuWindow`, don't need to extend `JFrame`. In any case you create a new `JFrame` in method `createSudokoWindow()` (of class `SudokuWindow`) so really no need for class `SudokuWindow` to extend `JFrame`.
2. `mainPanel.add(sB,BorderLayout.WEST);` Because you explicitly set the [layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) of `mainPanel` to `FlowLayout`, the `BorderLayout` constraints are ignored. If you want to use `BorderLayout` constraints then you need to set the layout manager for `mainPanel` to `BorderLayout`.
3. `frame.setPreferredSize(` Better you should not use `mainPanel` at all and instead use the content pane of the [JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) – whose default layout manager is `BorderLayout` – and set the preferred size of the `SudokuBoard` and add it to `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

Class `SudokuBoard`:

1. Set its layout manager to `GridLayout` and set its preferred size. Then you don't have to worry about explicitly setting sizes for each `JFormattedTextField`.
2. If you are going to override a painting method, then it almost always should be [paintComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and not `paint`. However you don't need to override any painting method since you should create the `JFormattedTextField`s in the constructor and set the background colors also in the constructor rather than in method `paint`.
3. As mentioned by @camickr in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73324781/joptionpane-behaving-weird-with-keylistener#comment129493149_73324781), you don't need a [KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) if you are using [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html).

Consider the following (which is my alternative solution):
(Notes and explanations after the code.)

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.LookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.UIDefaults;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class SudokuPuzzle {
    private static final int  COLS = 9;
    private static final int  ROWS = 9;
    private static final Color[][]  BACKGROUNDS;

    static {
        LookAndFeel laf = UIManager.getLookAndFeel();
        UIDefaults dflts = laf.getDefaults();
        Color dflt = (Color) dflts.get("TextField.background");
        Color mgnt = Color.magenta;
        BACKGROUNDS = new Color[][] {{mgnt, mgnt, mgnt, dflt, dflt, dflt, mgnt, mgnt, mgnt},
                                     {mgnt, mgnt, mgnt, dflt, dflt, dflt, mgnt, mgnt, mgnt},
                                     {mgnt, mgnt, mgnt, dflt, dflt, dflt, mgnt, mgnt, mgnt},
                                     {dflt, dflt, dflt, mgnt, mgnt, mgnt, dflt, dflt, dflt},
                                     {dflt, dflt, dflt, mgnt, mgnt, mgnt, dflt, dflt, dflt},
                                     {dflt, dflt, dflt, mgnt, mgnt, mgnt, dflt, dflt, dflt},
                                     {mgnt, mgnt, mgnt, dflt, dflt, dflt, mgnt, mgnt, mgnt},
                                     {mgnt, mgnt, mgnt, dflt, dflt, dflt, mgnt, mgnt, mgnt},
                                     {mgnt, mgnt, mgnt, dflt, dflt, dflt, mgnt, mgnt, mgnt}};
    }

    private void buildAndDisplayGui() throws ParseException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sudoku!");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createBoard(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createBoard() throws ParseException {
        JPanel board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 9));
        board.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
                board.add(createSquare(row, col));
            }
        }
        return board;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 20));
        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(buttonsPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
        buttonsPanel.setLayout(layout);
        buttonsPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Import solvable setup");
        buttonsPanel.add(button1);
        buttonsPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Find solution");
        button2.setMaximumSize(button1.getMaximumSize());
        buttonsPanel.add(button2);
        buttonsPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
        JTextField t1 = new JTextField("0");
        t1.setMaximumSize(button1.getMaximumSize());
        buttonsPanel.add(t1);
        buttonsPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JFormattedTextField createSquare(int row, int col) throws ParseException {
        MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("#");
        formatter.setValidCharacters("123456789");
        JFormattedTextField ftf = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        ftf.setColumns(2);
        ftf.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        ftf.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,26));
        ftf.setBackground(BACKGROUNDS[row][col]);
        return ftf;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SudokuPuzzle puzzle = new SudokuPuzzle();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                puzzle.buildAndDisplayGui();
            }
            catch (ParseException xParse) {
                xParse.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

1. I don't see a need for a `SudokuBoard` class that extends `JPanel` since there is no need to override any of `JPanel` class methods.
2. Since the valid characters are 1 - 9, I can't set the text of each `JFormattedTextField` to 0 (zero), hence the `JFormattedTextField`s are initially all empty.
3. Default behavior of `JFormatedTextField`, when entering an invalid value, is to beep. If you want to display a `JOptionPane` instead then I think you will need to write your own formatter and use that instead of `MaskFormatter`. I felt it was too much work for me so I just left the default behavior.

Here is how it looks:

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not expect such a comprehensive answer. You rewrote the code and everything! Solved my issues completely! Again thanks a bunch!